# What is the single word to describe a person who always likes to "celebrate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

(edited) I am having trouble finding a single word to describe a person who likes to "celebrate". This is different from "party animal", "clubber", "reveller" or "socialite". Specifically, I am looking for a noun that is designated for such a person.

The said person has the personality that simply enjoys being with friends and likes to find occasions to celebrate, in good spirits. In addition,
the said person not only goes to party, but s/he takes the initiative to propose having one to celebrate (an event/life/news...etc) whenever s/he finds the opportunity to do so.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: _Somebody_ defined the type 'celebrator': "This person is someone who is the life of the party, always happy, and has never met a person he doesn’t like, since he is always looking for the good in people. “The difficulty with the celebrator is that as quickly as the rain changes directions, this person can change. They will jump from one idea to the other before you have anything finalized,”". http://www.castool.com/blog/2013/05/four-personality-types-you-are-likely-meet-when-selling But maybe stick to 'big celebrator'?

Comment: I'd suggest "gregarious" https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gregarious .  It doesn't have the same potentially negative connotations of "party animal" (drug or alcohol dependence) or "socialite" (shallow).

Comment: How about **social butterfly**? What's wrong with **socialite**? To my knowledge it's not a *negative* word..

Comment: Someone like that would definitely be an "extrovert", but that's certainly not specific enough.

Comment: Perhaps it's because of the influence from the media, I tend to associate the words/terms "social butterfly", "socialite" and "party animal" with a negative connotation. Strictly speaking, the situations I had in mind do conform to the definition of "party", and as such, a person who likes to do things "in a party" can technically be described by all the aforementioned terms. But I am hoping someone else may come up with a term, other than celebrator, which is a good one for me, that conveys the simple idea of someone who is social and likes to celebrate. Thanks to all who have contributed.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, yes, I would be looking for a noun that describes someone who is gregarious. But unfortunately, none comes up in my mind.

Comment: @BChen your question doesn't mention a noun, it just says "a single word to describe".  If you want a noun then you should edit your question to state that.

Comment: @MaxWilliams. My bad, I have updated my original question to clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

The perfect word, I think, would be ***convivial***, [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convivial)

> enjoying good company; sociable; characterized by merry celebrating; festive: *a convivial atmosphere at the reunion.*

So you could say of the person to whom you refer:

> My friend is such a *convivial* fellow that he would like to attend a party every night of the week if he could!

Answer (score 1):

*Collins* offers two definitions of *[party-goer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/partygoer)*

> 1. a person at a party:
>
> *Chants from the drunken party-goers woke residents and the police were called.*
>
> *At least half the party-goers were under 15.*
>
> 2. a person who goes to a lot of parties:
>
> *Nigel Coates, the architect, party-goer and motorbike owner*

There is also the term *[life of the party](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/the-life-of-the-party)*

> A vivacious and sociable person.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

*[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/the+life+of+the+party)* amplifies

> he life of the party (Informal):
>   An animated, amusing person who is the center of attention at a social gathering.

citing *American Heritage*